# API for datapackages?

Tags: api, releasing-data, tool-request

Is there an API solution for [datapackages](http://data.okfn.org/doc/data-package) which can be self-hosted?

(Ideally something more lightweight than CKAN that can run on Heroku or similar.)

Overall I am looking for a solution which allows an organization to work with CSV files and create an API from this without too much hassle - so any other solutions to this are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

CKAN apparently, although I haven't done this myself CKAN is a good solution: http://okfnlabs.org/blog/2014/09/11/data-api-for-data-packages-with-dpm-and-ckan.html

Comment: Thanks! I read that article sometime ago and it is indeed very interesting. CKAN however seems a bit overkill for what I am trying to achieve, but maybe I should reconsider ...?

Comment: CKAN is good, I've had trouble installing it onto Ubunutu but then my dependencies are a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [migadv](http://migadv.com/). I am not sure if it is API enough, but it allows you to put your CSV with its metadata online.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good answer because migadv is one of many places to upload data and allow folks to browse it via web/API. The OP was asking specifically about the OKFN datapackages standard.

Comment: Yes, it is not OKFN datapackages standard. Sorry I overread this.

Comment: However, MigaDv is not a website for data upload. It is a PHP/javascript tool that requires your own webserver.

Comment: instead of "overread" I meant "overlook". Sorry for my poor English.